# Scrape webpages that are loaded using JavaScript function

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, html-parsing

I am currently attempting to scrape [this site](http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx) using jsoup.

#### My code so far:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Elements list = doc.getElementsByClass("name showframe");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() ; i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i).html() + " \n" + list.get(i).absUrl("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the code above only scrapes the first page out of 71 total pages which are loaded by calling a JavaScript function.

How can I scrape the other pages using jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript function in question simply sends a `POST` request to the same URL with different `__EVENTARGUMENT` which is the page's number.
You can easily get the other pages by mimicking this behavior:

#### Imports:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode;
```

#### Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String url = "http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx";
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0";
    try {
        Response  response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
        Document document = response.parse();

        String viewState = encode(document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").attr("value"), "UTF-8");
        String eventTarget = encode("p$lt$ctl12$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$UniPager$pagerElem", "UTF-8");

        for(int i = 1; i < 72; ++i) {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                .requestBody(
                        String.format(
                                "__EVENTTARGET=%s"
                                + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=%d"
                                + "&__VIEWSTATE=%s",
                                eventTarget, i, viewState ))
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .post();

            Elements list = document.getElementsByClass("name showframe");

            for (int x = 0; x < list.size() ; x++) {
                System.out.println(list.get(x).html() + " \n" + list.get(x).absUrl("href"));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Handle exceptions
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome...thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

so, finally got this one...

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.net.URLEncoder.encode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Participants.csv"), "windows-1251");
        final String colNames = "Name;Country;Address;Phone;Fax;Site;Descr";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(colNames + "\n");

        final String url = "http://www.world-food.ru/ru-RU/about/exhibitor-list.aspx";
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36";

        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
        Document document = response.parse();
        String viewState = encode(document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE").attr("value"), "UTF-8");
        String eventTarget = encode("p$lt$ctl12$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl01$UniPager$pagerElem" , "UTF-8");

        for (int i = 1; i <=71 ; i++) {
            document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                    .requestBody(
                            String.format(
                                    "__EVENTTARGET=%s" + "&__EVENTARGUMENT=%d" + "&__VIEWSTATE=%s",
                                    eventTarget, i , viewState ))
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .post();

            Elements subList = document.getElementsByClass("name showframe");
            for (int j = 0; j < subList.size(); j++) {
                Document compPage = Jsoup.connect(subList.get(j).absUrl("href")).post();
                Elements compPageData = compPage.getElementsByClass("name");

                builder.append(subList.get(j).html().replace(';',',') + ";");
//                System.out.println(subList.get(j).html().replace(';',',') + ";");
                builder.append(subList.get(j).siblingElements().first().text()+ ";");
//                System.out.println(subList.get(j).siblingElements().first().text()+ ";");

                for (int k = 0; k <compPageData.size() ; k++) {
                    builder.append(compPageData.get(k).siblingElements().text().replace(';', ',') + ";");
//                    System.out.print(compPageData.get(k).siblingElements().text().replace(';', ',') + ";");
                }
                builder.append('\n');
            }
        }
        pw.write(builder.toString());
        pw.close();
    }
}
```